# how can I get tag depending on attributes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to pick up this tag by simple_dom_html

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

I can get the title like this.

```
$title = $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;
```

However how can I get items depending on property?

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="480">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="360">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/test.jpg">
</head>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "how can I get items depending on property" ok I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  simple dom html you could do something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

$m = $html->find("meta[property=og:image:width]"); //selects meta tag(s) where property=og:image:width

$m2 = $html->find("meta[content=360]"); //selects meta tag(s) where content=360
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this document , everything neatly explained http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm